# Save grep result to array

Tags: bash, files, scripting, array

I want to save all filenames that matches the pattern in bash array.

My solution does not work. I think the problem is because of pipe usage, but I don't know how to fix it.

```
i=0
find . -type f | grep -oP "some pattern" | while read -r line; do
    arr[$i]=$line;
    let i=i+1;
done
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `bash-4.4` and above, you'd use:

```
readarray -d '' -t arr < <(
  find . -type f -print0 | grep -zP 'some pattern')
```

With older `bash` versions:

```
arr=()
while IFS= read -rd '' file; do
  arr+=("$file")
done < <(find . -type f -print0 | grep -zP 'some pattern')
```

Or (to be compatible to even older versions of `bash` that didn't have the zsh-style `arr+=()` syntax):

```
arr=() i=0
while IFS= read -rd '' file; do
  arr[i++]=$line
done < <(find . -type f | grep -zP 'some pattern')
```

Your approach has several problems:

- with `-o`, `grep` only prints the parts of the records that match the pattern as opposed to the full record. You don't want it here.
- `find`'s default newline-delimited output can't be post processed as the newline character is as valid as any in a file path. You need a NUL-delimited output (so `-print0` in `find` and `-z` in `grep` to process NUL-delimited records.
- you also forgot to pass `IFS=` to `read`.
- in `bash`, and without the `lastpipe` option, the last part of a pipe line runs in a subshell, so there, you'd only be updating the `$arr` of that subshell.